# Can we serve static files from Tomcat FASTER than NginX/Apache?

Tags: nginx, tomcat

The following data was from testing on my own windows machine(SSD) on localhost.
When I download static content from Nginx, I get upto 120-140 MBps(I am sure it can optimized further. Nginx actually claims it can reach a throughput of upto 0.98 Gbps). And this was being done, with almost negligible increase in cpu/memory consumption increase. 
I have tried to do the same in tomcat, and the max speed when downloading files is upto 25 Mbps. Also, this consumes 15-25% of cpu usage as per task manager.
My machine has a SSD, so no, the file reading isn't taking time or increasing cpu usage.

Can the file serving part be improved? 
I.E serving faster download speeds with lesser cpu consumption.

```
<Connector port="29022" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol" useSendfile="true" connectionTimeout="300000"/>
```

I am using Nio2 connector. Should I tweak any more of the connector settings, or use Nio/apr connector?

All file download requests are delegated to a threadpool using an asynchronous servlet call : request.setAttribute("org.apache.catalina.ASYNC_SUPPORTED", true);

The threads from the thread pool(thread pool size is 2) will serve each of the requests in a round robin fashion in a loop. In each loop iteration, the following code is executed to send about 8 KB(8192 Bytes).

```
if(bytesSent < toBeServedFileSize){
    if(!buffer.hasRemaining()){
        buffer.clear();
        fileChannel.read(buffer,bytesSent);
        buffer.flip();
    }
    int bytesToWrite = Math.min(buffer.remaining(), streamPacketSize);
    byte[] byteAr = new byte[bytesToWrite];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < bytesToWrite ; i++){byteAr[i] = buffer.get();}
    //I'm guessing below is the most cpu intensive line
    os.write(byteAr);
    //I am guessing above is the most cpu intensive line
    bytesSent += bytesToWrite;
}
```

The whole purpose of this exercise is to both authenticate and authorise the file download requests. I think serving static content from apache/NginX don't have good solutions to address this requirement. Suggestions and alternate solutions are welcome.

Comment: Seems like you have two different Questions here. One is “How can I configure Tomcat to most quickly serve static files?”. That should be asked on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), it is a server config question, not a programming question. The second Question is analyzing the techniques used within the Tomcat source code. That Question is appropriate on Stack Overflow, but should be reframed as its own explicit Question with a title and body focused on that one issue.

Comment: By the way, regarding your phrase “My machine has a SSD, so no, the file reading isn't taking time”, correction: Reading files from storage *always* takes time. Even SSDs are vastly slower than RAM. We have no non-volatile storage technology that comes close to the speed of RAM. Furthermore, most file systems transparently cache data read from storage, so it is not obvious when you are retrieving your static files from storage or from RAM cache.